# What is the intended workflow for Custom Validators in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I've been trying to implement a system for custom error validation in my ASP.Net app, but have had some issues figuring what is the expected workflow when implementing custom validators within the pipeline.
I have created my own Validators by deriving from IModelValidatorProvider and using the intended "Validate" method to generate IModelValidator instances, and they work as you'd expect. My issue however is that I'd like to pass a custom Error object back to my client on Validation failure, much like you could do when returning an Asp.Net IActionResult.
For example, IActionFilter allows you to add an IActionResult object to your ActionExecutedContext, which can then be processed by the framework along with whatever object you may have passed in it, and I'd like to do the same, but without having to go through the trouble of tagging every method with an IActionFilter attribute.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is your asp.net version?

Comment: If you need more help, maybe we can talk in discord Ricardo#1318